# Inserting record into database column with auto number

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to add a record to my database using the following function

The Error occurs at

```
adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Full code:

```
public void Insert()
{
        string query;
        myDB.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * From Eiendom", myDB);
        query = @"INSERT INTO Eiendom (AreaID, AgentID, KlientID, AdresID, EiedomAantalBadkamers, EiedomAantalSlaapkamers, EiendomPrys, EiedomSwembad, EiedomGarages, EiedomAantalVloere, EiedomOppervlakte, EiedomTipePlan, EiedomAdisioneleInligting) 
                  VALUES ('" + areaID + " , " + agentID + " , " + klientID + " , " 
        + adressID + " , " + badkamers + " , " + slaapkamers + " , " + prys + " . "
        + " , " + swembad + " , " + garages + " , " + vloere + " , " + oppervlakte
        + " , " + plan + " , " + inligting + "')" ;

        OleDbCommand insert = new OleDbCommand(query, myDB);

        adapter.InsertCommand = insert;
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Eiendom");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Eiendom";
        myDB.Close();
 }
```

I get an error that says ;

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.'

I actually do understand as to why this is presenting itself as I am not adding the autonumber column I have in my database

[image: Database Screen Print]

So what I'm asking is what can I do as a workaround to add the record but the auto number column fills itself in when adding the record?

Comment: That is very much **not** the way to compose a query - and has been the right way for a long time.  Research SQL Parameters ASAP. as well as [xkcd](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png)

Comment: Any helpful advice? Rather then telling me I'm not up to date? As I am a student and learning. @Plutonix

Comment: Helpful advise is baked in: *Research SQL Parameters*

Comment: Cool thank you anyway......... @Plutonix

Comment: Try removing the two apostrophes from the SQL construct. You also have a period where there should be a comma after `prys + `.

Comment: @June7 If the columns contain values not of type numeral types, you need apostrophes (around each value). But regardless of that, this way of building SQL statements is error prone and insecure.

Comment: @jAC, see HansUp answer. These apostrophes are not used correctly. Yes, apostrophe delimiters for text fields.

Comment: @June7 I'm very well aware of how SQL statements are built. I'm simply stating, that removing apostrophes will fix this statement is not correct.

Comment: Disagree, the fields are all number type. And those two apostrophes are not used correctly.

Comment: Not all fields are of number type 2 are of boolean and one of string

Comment: @June7 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.' When removing all apostrophes.

Comment: There are only 2 apostrophes that need to be removed/fixed. I am not talking about quote marks. Well, the string field doesn't show in image. Use apostrophe delimiters for that parameter. Boolean field is a number type as it contains either 0 or -1. Did you change the indicated period to comma?

Comment: @June7 yes ive read it and aplied it as well, tells me the same error as in the problem i stated

Comment: Okay, and did you fix the period that should be a comma? Edit question to the revised attempted SQL.

Comment: @June7 Yes I have,  but I see how he mentioned in his solution that I should switch to a parameter query, and I see how it would be much easier and safer to do it that way. I'm yet to have success but I'm trying my best. I'll post my solution as soon as I have one. Thank you for the help. I appreciate it alot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hand craft your InsertCommamd. The OleDbCommandBuilder can do it all for you. I think it should deal with Autonumbers.

```
var cbr = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
cbr.QuotePrefix = "[";
cbr.QuoteSuffix = "]";
adapter.InsertCommand = cbr.GetInsertCommand(true);
```